# Swift Hide/Show Text fields and buttons based on text

Tags: ios, swift

Been having a time with this, working on scene that allows user to put in their Extension Number, `myExtension`, and Description, `myText`, then they click take photo (`takePhoto`). Next the camera opens, the user takes a photo, it loads the image in an image viewer, then there is a save button, `saveImage`, that uploads the image to web server.  This all works great... but to save the hassle of ill-named images, I want to disable all fields and buttons until text is entered.

For example: Extension unlocks Description, Description unlocks TAKE PHOTO BUTTON, and Save is not activated until image view is not null.  And maybe hide the image view until photo is taken.

I need the user to take multiple photos, so I would want the text to stay in the fields, but after I take photo clear image view and hide, allowing them to tap Take photo again.

Note: I append the date time to the file name so it will not over write file.

Attached is the controller code. Any help is appreciated. I've tried a few options but can't seem to get it working right.

```
import UIKit

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var myExtension: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var takePhoto: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveImage: UIButton!

@IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    myImageUploadRequest()
}

@IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self;
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //myImageUploadRequest()
}    

func myImageUploadRequest()
{
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://website.com/api/upload1.php");        
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "myText"  : myText.text!,
        "myExtension" : myExtension.text!
    ]

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)
    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)

    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(response)")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

        //Update
        //            var err: NSError?
        //            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult) }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.myImageView.image = nil;
        });
    }

    task.resume()
}


func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }


    var now: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMDDyyyy"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    var time: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmmss"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    let filename = (myText.text! + "_" + now + time + ".jpg")

    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")



    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}



func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}



}


extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        appendData(data!)

    }

}
```

Comment: So your question is, given a view, how to enable and disable some subset of child views (buttons, etc) all at once?

Comment: 2 Text Fields and a button to start. Must enter "myExtension" in order to enter "myText". Once both have text enable "takePhoto" button.

Comment: Then when Image View is not blank, Enable a "Save" Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With multiple trial and error I got this working.

Basically I created a function to do all the checking.

thanks...